# Запрос select на vba

Tags: access, vba, sql

Здравствуйте,

Пишу программку на access. Есть загвоздка.

Выполняю sql запрос:

```
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT deti FROM deti WHERE rodit NOT IN (SELECT id FROM rodit);")
dwr = rs2.GetRows(rs2.RecordCount)
```

В итоге получаю в `dwr` только одну строчку из полученного запроса, а не несколько, как должно быть. Пробовал просто в запросах написать данный запрос,

все работает, а почему-то в vba не получается???

Надеюсь на помощь!

Answer (score 2):

У тебя `RecordCount` - всегда будет 1, пока не пробежишь по рекордсету:

```
rs2.MoveLast
rs2.MoveFirst
```

А только после этого `dwr = rs2.GetRows(rs2.RecordCount)`.